# Как связать сайт с базой данных телеграм бота?

Tags: javascript, php, python-3.x, json

У меня есть Telegram бот с базой данных SQLite3, в которой хранятся товары.

SQLite3(id, name, description, sale)

Как связать сайт с базой данных Telegram бота? Или как сделать запрос в базу данных Telegram бота?

Это должно работать так: я на сайте ввожу запрос ***мойсайт.ру/123123***, где 123123 - это id товара из базы данных бота. И на сайт подгружается вся информация об этом товаре из базы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разверени ноду и подключи к базе данных

```
const app = express();
const http = createServer(app);
app.get("/:id", MyController.getItem);


http.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Server: http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});

потом обработай контролером 

class MyController {
getItem = (req, res) => {
 так достаешь ид из запроса
 const id = req.params.id;
 дальше работаешь с бд 
}
}
```